# Translation from english into a phonetic Cantonese "Forces of Evil, Come and Obey."

Tags: cantonese

I'm a writer. I am trying to get "Forces of Evil, Come and Obey" or something with the same general meaning translated to phonetic Cantonese so I can have a character use it like a chant in a story intended for an English speaking audience.

Like 'Yu Mo Gui Gwai Fai Di Zao' is able to be chanted and understood by an American audience.

Comment: How would 'Yu Mo Gui Gwai Fai Di Zao' be able to be understood by an American audience?

Comment: As individual syllables that they can repeat verbally.

Comment: 'Yu Mo Gui Gwai Fai D Zao'  sounds like "妖魔鬼怪快啲走" in Cantonese. It means "Evil demons and unholy ghost, hurry and be gone"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chinese slogans typically come in  idiomatic (four characters) phrase

if "*Forces of Evil, Come and Obey*" means "**we are the forces of Evil, come and obey us**" then  I suggest:

> "道消魔長，順我者昌"
>
> "(the power of) good has declined and (the power of) evil has grown; those who submit to us flourish"

jyutping: /dou2 siu1 mo1 coeng2 seon6 ngo5 ze2 coeng1/

phonetic: "doe siu mor zhung, Shun wu jer chun"

*And it rhymes*

If "*Forces of Evil, Come and Obey*" means "**you, the forces of evil, come and obey me**' then I suggest:

> "道長魔消，逆我者亡" (the power of) evil has declined and (the power of) good has grown; those who resist us perish"

jyutping: /dou2 coeng2 mo1 siu1/, /jik6  ngo5 ze2 mong4/

phonetic: "doe zhung mor siu, yiey wu jer mong"